# Can I disable Google Analytics for a specific user in a mobile app from backend only without an in app toggle switches?

Tags: mobile-application, privacy, google-analytics-firebase

I could not find such answer. Is it possible to keep analytics enabled for all but disable it for one person? Assuming there are no toggles in an app which user can use directly and I want to do that from a back end only when a specif user requests it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, but it's entirely up to you. If your app loads Google Analytics without it being provided by the back-end, you could provide it in a response, say when the user logs in. The response to your auth endpoint could provide some optional data, something like:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "token": "abc123xyz",
    "useanalytics": false
}
```

and then your app logic could use that to disable analytics from the client side, without needing an in-app toggle.

One thing to bear in mind – Google Analytics is not strictly necessary for the operation of an app, and is currently illegal to use in the EU (because it ships data to the USA), so I would recommend that if you want to use it, it would have to be enabled explicitly by the user after appropriate warnings. This probably applies to Firebase too.

Comment: Thank for your insight. Yes you are right about the data flow plus GA is not strictly necessary (similarly to cookies on a website for GA). Schrems II case bothers many parties. I encouraged to go with toggles but in a current version of an app I need to be able to address the right to object data processing under GDPR this way until new release. Thank again!